# Getting rid of characters when doing gf in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I am using `vim` for coding. When I have something like the following:
`SomeModule->actualMethod()` if I take the cursor to `SomeModule` and I do a `gf` I get a complaint that `SomeModule-` does not exist in the path.
How can I get rid of the `-` so that the `SomeModule` file opens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Vim considers part of a filename is controlled by the `'isfname'` option. You need to remove the dash from it for your example to work:

```
:set isfname-=-
```

Note that when your `SomeModule` file has a file extension, you also need to add it to `'suffixesadd'`.

Comment: So the `=-` means that what comes after `=` is not part of a filename? And if I need to exclude other characters? E.g. a `-` and a `:` as not acceptable parts of filename?

Comment: The `-=` deletes the following string from `isfname`. See `:help :set-=`. If you wish to delete other characters from `isfname`, be sure to delete them one character at a time. That is, execute `:set isfname-=-` and `:set isfname-=:`, _not_ `:set isfname-=-:`. The last command will work only if `-:` are present in `isfname` together and in that order.